# Delete all item from a 'TreeView' in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with too many elements when I bind it. It's pretty fast because I use beginUpdate and endUpdate, but when I say

```
treeView.beginUpdate();

treeView.items.clear();

treeView.endUpdate();
```

it does not take the same efficiency as when I add. When I clear all items, it's taking a long time and does not pause the UI.

Comment: Why begin update on the view and end update on the items?  Why not end update on the view as well?

Comment: Save the list of items somewhere, recreate the treeview control, and repopulate it. It will be way faster.

Comment: Do you have a single root node? In that case, you can just remove that root node, taking all of its children with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the Nodes collection has more than 200 items, the BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods are called automatically by the Clear() method, which is why you propbably didn't really notice any difference.

This, however, doesn't help you very much since what the Clear() method does is that it walks the entire tree and removes all children, which of course takes a lot of time. Unfortunately the Nodes property is read-only, so you can't just initalize the TreeViewNodeCollection.

Recreating the TreeView control - as Daro suggested - would probably be a viable option as it is really fast, HOWEVER it doesn't appear to release the memory immediately (calling Dispose() of course walks through all the nodes again). I tested it by forcing the garbage collection and it did clean it up, which means that sooner or later it probably *would* get cleaned up by automatically.

```
SuspendLayout();
    Controls.Remove(treeView1);
    treeView1 = new TreeView();
    treeView1.Location = new Point(39, 39);
    treeView1.Size = new Size(213, 210);
    Controls.Add(treeView1);
ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: This is missing `.Dispose()` which you should always call when you are about to loose reference to a `Control`. Resource Leaks are sure to occur otherwise. (Relying on GC for Controls will bite you)
Save a reference to the old treeview, and fire of a thread or similar that can do the proper disposal in the background if it takes to much time to do in current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try collapsing the TreeView first (assuming not all nodes are at the top level):

```
treeView.beginUpdate();
treeView.items.CollapseAll();
treeView.items.clear();
treeView.items.endUpdate();
```

Comment: So they are all top level nodes? Since you a removing all nodes, why not just trash the TreeView and create another in it's place?

Comment: create another one? on each deleteAll ? Wouldn't that imply a lot of memory consumption?

Comment: When you treeView.Dispose() the TreeNodes are "orphaned", but when they are no longer in scope, Garbage Collection will get them.  You can also free up memory as soon as they go out of scope by forcing garbage collection with GC.Collect().

Comment: Any Control that you create should have `.Dispose()` called on them, if not you risk leaking memory (and other more critical resources). This goes for all control, as soon as you remove them, and are about to loose reference to it, call `.Dispose()`, always, always, always